# combining sets within a list

Tags: python, set

Hi so I'm trying to do the following but have gotten a bit stuck. Say I have a list of sets:

```
A = [set([1,2]), set([3,4]), set([1,6]), set([1,5])]
```

I want to create a new list which looks like the following:

```
B = [ set([1,2,5,6]), set([3,4]) ]
```

i.e create a list of sets with the sets joined if they overlap. This is probably simple but I can't quite get it right this morning.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have a code (even not working as expected)?

Comment: It sounds like you have a graph and you want to determine the transitive closure.  There are well-known algorithms for this.

Comment: Nope, no graph. A slightly more involved problem than the question I asked, but it boils down to the scenario in the question. So without copying my code, I'm iterating through the list (nested loop) checking if the sets contain common elements i.e. checking a&b where a and b are sets in the list (the combined set will be a|b in this case). I'm then trying to create a new list from this. (I'll post my broken code in a few minutes).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Here is a function that does what you want. Probably not the most pythonic one but does the job, most likely can be improved a lot.

```
from sets import Set

A = [set([1,2]), set([3,4]), set([2,3]) ]

merges = any( a&b for a in A for b in A if a!=b)
while(merges):
    B = [A[0]]
    for a in A[1:] :
        merged = False
        for i,b in enumerate(B):
            if  a&b :
                B[i]=b | a
                merged =True
                break

        if not merged:         
            B.append(a)
    A = B
    merges = any( a&b for a in A for b in A if a!=b)

print B
```

What is happening there is the following, we loop all the sets in A, (except the first since we added that to B already. We check the intersection with all the sets in B, if the intersection result anything but False (aka empty set) we perform a union on the set and start the next iteration, about set operation check this page:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html
& is intersection operator
| is union operator

You can probably go more pythonic using any() etc but wuold have required more processing so I avoided that

Comment: Ahh very neat. Thanks!

Comment: Actually this doesn't quite work for cases like this: A = [set([1,2]), set([3,4]), set([2,3]) ]

Comment: mmm interesting yes, let me think on it.

Comment: this problem reduces itself to a reduction problem so you need to keep applying the function until no possible merges are possible, have a look at the updated answer. let me know. I tested with both your use cases and seems to hold.
 ps , why downvote?

Comment: Ok thanks I'll look at it! I didn't down vote as far as I'm aware? Not sure what happened - sorry.

Comment: let me know, if you find any other tests that make the above function fail please let me know i am intrigued.

Answer (score 1):

This also works and is quite short:

```
import itertools

groups = [{'1', '2'}, {'3', '2'}, {'2', '4'}, {'5', '6'}, {'7', '8'}, {'7','9'}]

while True:
    for s1, s2 in itertools.combinations(groups, 2):
        if s1.intersection(s2):
            break
    else:
        break
    groups.remove(s1)
    groups.remove(s2)
    groups.append(s1.union(s2))

groups
```

This gives the following output:

```
[{'5', '6'}, {'1', '2', '3', '4'}, {'7', '8', '9'}]
```

The `while True` does seems a bit dangerous to me, any thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def sortOverlap(listOfTuples):

    # The locations of the values
    locations = defaultdict(lambda: [])

    # 'Sorted' list to return
    sortedList = []

    # For each tuple in the original list
    for i, a in enumerate(listOfTuples):

        for k, element in enumerate(a):

            locations[element].append(i)

    # Now construct the sorted list
    coveredElements = set()
    for element, tupleIndices in locations.iteritems():

        # If we've seen this element already then skip it
        if element in coveredElements:
            continue

        # Combine the lists
        temp = []
        for index in tupleIndices:

            temp += listOfTuples[index]

        # Add to the list of sorted tuples
        sortedList.append(list(set(temp)))

        # Record that we've covered this element
        for element in sortedList[-1]:
            coveredElements.add(element)

    return sortedList

# Run the example (with tuples)
print sortOverlap([(1,2), (3,4), (1,5), (1,6)])

# Run the example (with sets)
print sortOverlap([set([1,2]), set([3,4]), set([1,5]), set([1,6])])
```

Comment: Cool, but again this does not work with this for example: [set([1,2]), set([3,4]), set([2,3])]

Answer (score 0):

You could use intersection() and union() in for loops:

```
A = [set([1,2]), set([3,4]), set([1,6]), set([1,5])]

intersecting = []

for someSet in A:
    for anotherSet in A:
        if someSet.intersection(anotherSet) and someSet != anotherSet:
            intersecting.append(someSet.union(anotherSet))
            A.pop(A.index(anotherSet))

A.pop(A.index(someSet))

finalSet = set([])
for someSet in intersecting:
    finalSet = finalSet.union(someSet)

A.append(finalSet)

print A
```

Output: `[set([3, 4]), set([1, 2, 5, 6])]`

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more straightforward solution,

```
def overlaps(sets):
    overlapping = []
    for a in sets:
        match = False
        for b in overlapping:
            if a.intersection(b):
                b.update(a)
                match = True
                break
        if not match:
            overlapping.append(a)
    return overlapping
```

examples

```
>>> overlaps([set([1,2]), set([1,3]), set([1,6]), set([3,5])])
[{1, 2, 3, 5, 6}]
>>> overlaps([set([1,2]), set([3,4]), set([1,6]), set([1,5])])
[{1, 2, 5, 6}, {3, 4}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for set_ in A:
    new_set = set(set_)
    for other_set in A:
        if other_set == new_set:
            continue
        for item in other_set:
            if item in set_:
                new_set = new_set.union(other_set)
                break
    if new_set not in B:
        B.append(new_set)
```

Input/Output:

```
A = [set([1,2]), set([3,4]), set([2,3]) ]
B = [set([1, 2, 3]), set([2, 3, 4]), set([1, 2, 3, 4])]

A = [set([1,2]), set([3,4]), set([1,6]), set([1,5])]
B = [set([1, 2, 5, 6]), set([3, 4])]

A = [set([1,2]), set([1,3]), set([1,6]), set([3,5])]
B = [set([1, 2, 3, 6]), set([1, 2, 3, 5, 6]), set([1, 3, 5])]
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will do the job, without touching the input:

```
from copy import deepcopy


def remove_overlapped(input_list):
    input = deepcopy(input_list)
    output = []
    index = 1

    while input:
        head = input[0]
        try:
            next_item = input[index]
        except IndexError:
            output.append(head)
            input.remove(head)
            index = 1
            continue
        if head & next_item:
            head.update(next_item)
            input.remove(next_item)
            index = 1
        else:
            index += 1
    return output
```